# javascript array.push(array.push(x)) weird result

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

below is a solution to **leetcode's combination problem** https://leetcode.com/problems/combinations/. Basically, **n choose k**, return all possibilities. I am running into this problem inside my second for loop where you see

```
tmpResult[i].push(n);
result.push(tmpResult[i]);
```

If i do

```
result.push(tmpResult[i].push(n));
```

the result is very different and I get an error:
*Line 22: TypeError: tmpResult[i].push is not a function.*
I come from java world and what is javascript doing differently in that one line code that's different from the 2 lines above it?

```
var combine = function(n, k) {
    if (k === 0 || k > n)
        return [];

    var result = [];

    if (k === 1) {
        for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            result.push([i]);
        }
        return result;
    }
    // choose n
    var tmpResult = combine(n-1,k-1);

    for( var i = 0; i < tmpResult.length; i++) {
        tmpResult[i].push(n);
        result.push(tmpResult[i]);
        // below doesnt work
        // result.push(tmpResult[i].push(n));
    }

    // not choose n
    result = result.concat(combine(n-1, k));

    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.prototype.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

> The push() method adds one or more elements to the end of an array and
>   returns the new length of the array.

You're adding the length of the array to `result`, which is why `result.push(tmpResult[i].push(n));` doesn't work.

Comment: thank you, I should've looked at the api more carefully!

Answer (score 0):

The method push returns the new size of the array, not the array itself

Comment: thank you, I should've looked at the api more carefully!